# start and stop control not working youtube

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

I have tried to create custom start and stop in youtube video.Its working fine in reference fiddle [reference link](http://jsfiddle.net/8R5y6/)

I have tried in html file.Its not working in html file,I have given my code below

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <script>

 /*call player*/
function callPlayer(frame_id, func, args) {
    if (window.jQuery && frame_id instanceof jQuery) frame_id = frame_id.get(0).id;
    var iframe = document.getElementById(frame_id);
    if (iframe && iframe.tagName.toUpperCase() != 'IFRAME') {
        iframe = iframe.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
    }
    if (iframe) {
        // Frame exists, 
        iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify({
            "event": "command",
            "func": func,
            "args": args || [],
            "id": frame_id
        }), "*");
    }
}
</script>

  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="whateverID" class="video-container"><iframe width="640" height="390" id="yt" frameborder="0" title="YouTube video player" type="text/html" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/u1zgFlCw8Aw?enablejsapi=1"></iframe></div>
     <div  id="playButton" class="playVideo"><a href="javascript:void callPlayer(&quot;whateverID&quot;,&quot;playVideo&quot;)">Play button</a></div>
     <div class="close_icon" ><a href="javascript:void callPlayer(&quot;whateverID&quot;,&quot;pauseVideo&quot;)">Pause close</a></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your jsfiddle code working fine.

Comment: I have tried to do the same in sample file getting problem

Comment: What's that suppose to mean?

Comment: I tried the same in file but not working

Comment: please see my updated post

Comment: Sorry but still not getting your point. Does this mean you are trying on you local setup and it's not working on it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131226/discussion-between-user3386779-and-aavrug).

Comment: what error you get on console when you try to run it from html file?

Comment: @Oriel I didn't get any error in console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it sounds like your page didnt finish to load before the script start,

try to cut your script tag and move it to the end of the body like that(so your page will load first and then your script will load) :

```
  <html>
  <head>


  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="whateverID" class="video-container"><iframe width="640" height="390" id="yt" frameborder="0" title="YouTube video player" type="text/html" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/u1zgFlCw8Aw?enablejsapi=1"></iframe></div>
     <div  id="playButton" class="playVideo"><a href="javascript:void callPlayer(&quot;whateverID&quot;,&quot;playVideo&quot;)">Play button</a></div>
     <div class="close_icon" ><a href="javascript:void callPlayer(&quot;whateverID&quot;,&quot;pauseVideo&quot;)">Pause close</a></div>

<script>

 /*call player*/
function callPlayer(frame_id, func, args) {
    if (window.jQuery && frame_id instanceof jQuery) frame_id = frame_id.get(0).id;
    var iframe = document.getElementById(frame_id);
    if (iframe && iframe.tagName.toUpperCase() != 'IFRAME') {
        iframe = iframe.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
    }
    if (iframe) {
        // Frame exists, 
        iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify({
            "event": "command",
            "func": func,
            "args": args || [],
            "id": frame_id
        }), "*");
    }
}
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```